# Using pos:fixed to align div relatively to div

Tags: jquery, css

I need to make div with position: fixed be relative to parent div, not the window.
I know it's can be easily achieved with JS, example:

```
function sticky() {
    $('.sticky').css({ //sticky block
        left : $('.container').offset().left + parseInt($('.container').css('width'))
    });
}

sticky();

$(window).resize(function() {
    sticky();
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zcqbsrzf/

Point is, I need a sticky block which will be positioned just right after content block and scrolling with whole page, and it should be staying on it's place if window is resizing.

Is there any ways to achieve that using pure css, because I think JS like that would cause low performance on page.

Comment: `fixed` is always relative to the window. Use `position: absolute;` to position an element relative to its parent's position (which needs at least `position: relative;`).

Comment: Something like this.. right? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zcqbsrzf/2/)

Comment: Paul, then element would not be scrolling with the whole page. Mr_Green, yes, good idea to use something like that if container width is static, thanks, and it's not positioned just in the middle of page.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new value for position:

### [position:sticky](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-position/#sticky-pos)

NB: [Browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky) is currently limited to Firefox and safari

### **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/zcqbsrzf/6/)** (For Firefox and Safari)

Notice that `top:0;` is set, yet the sticky div is not located at the top of the viewport

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 5000px;
  background: gray;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.sticky {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: -100px;
  float: right;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky; /* <---- */
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">container
  <div class="sticky">sticky
  </div>
</div>
```